# Firebase - How can a firebase storage file become 'un-downloadable' from browser console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am saving audio files to the firebase.

> Files are saved for ex: 1533128684596.m4a

When I manually try to download a file from the console in Chrome, it opens a new tab with a corrupted audio file which can not be downloaded. (I have included a screenshot)

The same file can be accessed through a flutter app with

> getDownloadURL() and passing it to audioPlayer()

What am I missing? How can a Firebase storage file become 'un-downloadable' from browser-based GUI console?

[image: browser screenshot]

Comment: You probably have coding issue. However, what it is, we don't know because we can't see your code. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it is not a code issue. firebase storage console is a browser based GUI. I was expecting an answer which can explain how a firebase storage file becomes 'un-downloadable', If this is completely new and unexpected then could be a bug.

Comment: I was more referring to the saving of the file and/or being able to access it from *a flutter app* and/or in chrome (lots of variables there). Did you try accessing it in Safari?

Comment: I will try to update the question with code that can be used to repro error since it doesn't look like common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If meta-data (in my case "audio/m4a") for the uploaded file is not set then it sometimes becomes un-downloadable from the browser.

In the app, to play the file from the URL, it doesn't need to have metadata attached.

These files can be downloaded with Wget tool.